# Where is php7 bin? PHP

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install a PHP Extension on my Linux Server however the installation process is confusing.

They provide this instructions.

```
git clone https://github.com/longxinH/xhprof.git ./xhprof
cd xhprof/extension/
/path/to/php7/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/path/to/php7/bin/php-config
make && sudo make install
```

I done git clone on PHP Extensions Folder

The thing that confuse me is

```
/path/to/php7/bin/phpize
```

Where is php7 bin?

The closest thing i found is /usr/bin/php
but its an executable file.

Inside this directory

```
/usr/bin/
```

I have php , php7.4, php-config, phpconfig7.4

Comment: Hi, the path they give is an example - `bin` is the parent directory of your `php` 7 executable, so in your case `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Should I /usr/bin/php7.4 phpize?

Comment: the folder is your choice. Hence the parameter where you can set it. I would use /usr/local or a subfolder of /opt (FHS) or if it is only for dev some folder in my home  - but it is entirely your choice. Looks like your dist uses /usr (but do you realy want to  mix upstream with self compiled -> updates may fail).